# What is the difference between ListView and ListView.builder and can we use Listview.builder to create and validate and submit forms?

Tags: flutter

What is the difference between Listview.builder and Listview?
Can we use ListView.builder to submit forms?

I am using the Listview.builder now to create forms.

Answer (score 45):

From official docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html

> ListView: Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets from an
>   explicit List.
>   This constructor is appropriate for list views with a small number of
>   children because constructing the List requires doing work for every
>   child that could possibly be displayed in the list view instead of
>   just those children that are actually visible.

---

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

> ListView.builder Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that
>   are created on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views
>   with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is
>   called only for those children that are actually visible.

Basically, `builder` constructor create a lazy list. When user is scrolling down the list, Flutter builds widgets "on demand".

Default ListView constructor build the whole list at once.

In your case, default construct works fine, because you already now how many widgets should put on Column().

Comment: Thanks, but i disagree with one thing, Default ListView constructor DOES NOT build and render the whole list at once always, but it really loads the entire list in memory at once.

Comment: I think the items which are not visible will be disposed in listview.builder

Comment: Can we always use Listview.builder instead of Listview? even in small lists.

Answer (score 14):

The main difference between **ListView and ListView.builder**

The `ListView` constructor requires us to create all items at once. This is good when list items are less and all will be seen on the screen, but if not then for long list items its not the good practice.

whereas

the `ListView.Builder` constructor will create items as they are scrolled onto the screen like on-demand. This is the best practice for development for List widget where items will only render only when items are going seen on the screen.

Comment: Can we always use Listview.builder instead of Listview? even in small lists.

Answer (score 7):

ListView.builder() builds widgets as required(when they can be seen). This process is also called "lazily rendering widgets".

Answer (score 1):

To see the difference between each one go visit [ListView Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

And sure, you can create Forms with `ListView.builder()`, but I've found some problems trying it.

1. I can't put it into any `ListView()`, either `Column()`, to put them if there's any more items than just the `Form()`.
2. I couldn't even add a Button at the of the `ListView.builder()` even using a conditional to put it when the last index is reached. Because of that, you have to use `textInputAction: TextInputAction.done` to perform some kind of action at `onFieldSubmitted:`
3. The best way to get the Fields data I've found was to add them all into an `array` when the `onSaved:`method is called, and I don't think that's a good way to go (maybe it is).

With that being said, that's what I used to make it work:

```
body: Form(
    key: _key,
    child: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            validator: (text) {
              if (text.isEmpty) {
                return "The text is empty";
              }
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (text) {
              _onSaved();
            },
            onSaved: (text) {
              form.add(text);
            },
          );             
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),

void _onSaved() {
  if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
    _key.currentState.save();
    print(form);
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
I/flutter ( 7106): [fjjxjx, hxjxjcj, jxjxjfj, jfjfj, jxjxj]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use Listview Builder instead of Listview, we will get better performance for our app. The reason for this is that it will only load the currently displayed list in the UI or recycle the previously loaded list. so it's better to use Listview Builder when we have large datasets for our list.

Answer (score 0):

This answer for those who are coming from native android background.
ListView is like listview in android
ListView.builder is recyclerView in android

In case you don't know recyclerView only render those view which are visible in screen and reuse them again and again to save resources.
RecyclerView when there is alot of data.

Answer (score 0):

in simple words
listview.builder allocate memory on demand while listview get the memory at once