# Difference between ListView.builder vs manual list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can also create lists by this code that I can with ListView.builder so what differentiate both?

```
for(Item in List) View(Item);
```

I am new to development and trying to understand this.

Is it good if I use above approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272328/what-is-the-difference-between-listview-and-listview-builder-and-can-we-use-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When items are limited(not more but few) you can use `ListView` widget, but for many items (like as thousands of items, also created on demand) - You should use `ListView.builder`.

The difference between of them is: When you use `ListView`, all the items are rendered on screen. But when you use `ListView.builder`, items are rendered on demand. Only the items are visible on the screen and few of above & bottom are rendered.

[image: Simple Analogy]

For more:

[ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html)

[ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)

Comment: If i have just 10 items to show, then is my above way good?

Comment: @SulavParajuli yes.