# ListView itemBuilder method triggered on scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I am using a **ListView.separated** with the following itemBuilder:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _buildRow(dataList[index]);
              }
```

I noticed that this **_buildRow()** methods is triggered while I am scrolling. It seems to be triggered only the rows that are out of the screen while scrolling.

I do not use the **setState()** method within **_buildRow()**.
Also, I verified that the super method **build(BuildContext context)** is not triggered. It really only is the itemBuilder one.

I am not sure if this is a normal behavior. Is there a way to avoid the itemBuilder method to be re-triggered on scroll? If this is not possible, is there a way to trigger a method once the ListView build has been completed?

Comment: I believe that this answer should clarify everything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56272858/12964903

Comment: Yes, it's completely normal behavior. ListView builds its child according to needs. If your child is outside the list area, it doesn't build that child. Also when a child is shown on the screen and going out of the list area, it recycles that view for the next upcoming child pretty effeciently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView.separated` re-triggered its `itemBuilder` while scrolling, as it only loads items that are shown on screen, unlike ListView which loads all the items at the time of initialization, due to this `ListView` is not a good option for a long list.

This increases performance significantly when we have a long list and complex widget to render as an item of `ListView.separated`. This is the expected behavior mentioned in the question.