# Dart/Flutter: automatically generate the subwidget in a class

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the class below

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    final int num;
    MyWidget({this.num});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  WidgetA(),
  WidgetA(),
  WidgetA(),
//the WigetA will repeate itself depending on the num.
}

}
```

If MyWidget(num = 3), then there will be 3 WigetA in MyWidget.

How to build this function inside WigetA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ListView.builder`. Here's some example code:

```
class MyWidgetListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final int widgetCount;

  MyWidgetListViewBuilder(this.widgetCount);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widgetCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return WidgetA();
      },
    );
  }
}

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('I appear as often as necessary');
  }
}
```

It is of course also possible to build the `List<WidgetA>` using a separate function:

```
class MyWidgetListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final int widgetCount;

  MyWidgetListView(this.widgetCount);
  
  List<WidgetA> _buildWidgetAList() {
    final widgetAList = <WidgetA>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < widgetCount; i++) {
      widgetAList.add(WidgetA());
    }
    return widgetAList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: _buildWidgetAList());
  }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272328/what-is-the-difference-between-listview-and-listview-builder-and-can-we-use-list#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=ListView%3A%20Creates%20a%20scrollable%2C%20linear,widgets%20from%20an%20explicit%20List.&text=builder%20Creates%20a%20scrollable%2C%20linear,that%20are%20created%20on%20demand.) answer describes the differences between `ListView` and `ListView.builder`.